# How to format Carbon date as "5th Oct 2017" in PHP?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I use carbon for date processing.
I try to formate the date with human understandable format.

My Standard Input :

```
$date ="05-10-2017";
echo Carbon::parse($date)->format('d m Y);
```

This format return :

```
05 Oct 2017
```

But i want the number formation like,

```
2nd, 3rd, 4th....
```

So my expected formation is,

```
05th Oct 2017
```

Is this possible ?

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Well NORMALLY you take a look at the manual. READ it and go from there

Comment: Yah. Manual tells everything. I respect you. But you should know one thing, Manual not always Up-To-Date...

Comment: I doubt that the parameters for a `->format()` have changed in 20 years

Comment: Ha Ha Ha.... Cool Cool... I'm just kidding... 
I just confuse with this formation so only i rise....

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

There is a table with available formats.

```
echo Carbon::parse($date)->format('dS M Y'); //05th Oct 2017
echo Carbon::parse($date)->format('jS M Y'); //5th Oct 2017
```

Comment: You may also use `format(''l jS \\of F Y')` which would give `Thursday 5th of October 2017`. Just saying it because the OP asked for `of` to be in the date aswell.